# Issues scheduling a Selenium .py script to run at a particular time

Tags: scheduler, windows-task-scheduler, python-3.10

I have a python script I have written to automate the booking of a round of golf through my golf club's website. This script logs in to my account and waits until the booking sheet opens (every Wednesday at 2pm) and then books myself and my group in at a designated time slot. The script has an explicit wait until the countdown timer reaches 0 and the link becomes clickable at which point it proceeds with the rest of the script.

Currently I am initialising the script manually through IDLE just prior to 2pm and it is working perfectly however I would like to automate the process such that I don't have to be at my computer in case I forget. I have tried this already using Task Scheduler however it doesn't appear to honour my wait and ends the script instead.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and if so how were they able to correct it? Alternatively is there a better way to schedule the running of this script at a given time instead of through Task Scheduler?

Thanks

As discussed above I have tried scheduling using Task Scheduler however it doesn't appear to be working. My guess is that there is some issue with the wait as if I test run it through TS on a booking sheet that is already open (i.e. not locked) it behaves as expected however if the sheet is locked it ends prematurely.